# Performance joining rows where date is between a start and end date

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have 2 tables with a couple of thousand rows each that I need to join based on a datetime between 2 datetimes.

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE * from A 
left outer join R on R.ActivityDate > A.StartDate and R.ActivityDate < A.EndDate;
```

The query is quite slow currently. I have tried adding indexes but they are not being used according to the output of explain. What is the appropriate indexing strategy for such a query? Using between doesn't instead of < > doesn't seem to make a difference.

If a straight join is performed the query is 13 times faster (7% less rows returned) but logically I need the unmatched rows to be returned. I wouldn't expect the difference between the 2 join types to be so large when the number of additional rows is so low. Why is the outer join so much slower?

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

```
mysql> describe A;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StartDate | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EndDate   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Data      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe R;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ActivityDate | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Leads        | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Using `<` and/or `>` usually won't use an index.

Comment: I am not sure if you would get any improvement, but have you tried `BETWEEN` instead of `>` and `<`?

Comment: I have tried between. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Why don't the tables have an auto_increment ID field ?

Answer (score 1):

Doing an LEFT JOIN would force all rows from A to appear regardless of the match

STRAIGHT JOIN or INNER JOIN would produce only rows matching the ON clause

Comment: Logically I need unmatched rows to be returned since I need to display the data from A even if there are no matching rows in R.

Comment: Why don't the tables have an auto_increment ID field ?

Comment: I have striped down the real tables for the question. A has an auto increment id.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE 
   * 
from A 
left outer join R 
  on ((R.ActivityDate - A.StartDate) * (R.ActivityDate - A.EndDate)) / 
      (CASE WHEN ABS((R.ActivityDate - A.StartDate) * (R.ActivityDate - A.EndDate)) = 0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE ABS((R.ActivityDate - A.StartDate) * (R.ActivityDate - A.EndDate)) 
       END) = -1
```

The on clause in the above is logically equal to the one presented in your question.

The reason for that the product `(R.ActivityDate - A.StartDate) * (R.ActivityDate - A.EndDate)` is negative only if `(R.ActivityDate > A.StartDate) and (R.ActivityDate < A.EndDate)` condition is satisfied.

It's so because of small transformation of the above condition `(R.ActivityDate - A.StartDate) > 0 and (R.ActivityDate - A.EndDate) < 0`.

Please try whether the execution time will improve since there are no `>` `<` comparisons in your query.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That is interesting but the performance is approximately the same ,  a tiny bit slower.

Comment: Thx for trying this out in your case and also for yor reply :) Regards.